# Error compiling Ceylon example with Gradle

Tags: gradle, plugins, ceylon

Ceylon 1.3.1 has just been released, one of the new items is better integration with Java projects/libraries. Decided to take one of the samples for a spin (https://github.com/DiegoCoronel/ceylon-spring-boot) alongside the ceylon-gradle plugin (https://github.com/renatoathaydes/ceylon-gradle-plugin).

As far as I can tell, turning this project into a multi-project Gradle build is a matter of adding two files with the following configuration.

*settings.gradle*

```
include 'gateway'
include 'discovery'
include 'foo'
include 'bar'
include 'foobar'
```

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.athaydes.ceylon' version '1.3.0' apply false
}

subprojects { subprj ->
    subprj.apply plugin: 'com.athaydes.ceylon'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    ceylon {
        module = subprj.name
    }
}
```

Unfortunately building any of the modules results in errors, such as

```
$ gradle :gateway:compileCeylon

:gateway:resolveCeylonDependencies
:gateway:createDependenciesPoms
:gateway:createMavenRepo
:gateway:generateOverridesFile
:gateway:createModuleDescriptors
:gateway:importJars
:gateway:compileCeylon
source/gateway/module.ceylon:3: error: Pre-resolving of module failed: Could not find module: antlr/2.7.7
        import ceylon.interop.java "1.3.0";
        ^
ceylon compile: There was 1 error
:gateway:compileCeylon FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gateway:compileCeylon'.
> Ceylon process exited with code 1. See output for details.
```

This happens using Gradle 3.2

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-11-14 12:32:59 UTC
Revision:     5d11ba7bc3d79aa2fbe7c30a022766f4532bbe0f

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_112 (Oracle Corporation 25.112-b16)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64
```

Tried setting additional properties on the `ceylon` configuration as explained in the plugin's documentation, such as

```
ceylon {
    flatClasspath = false
    importJars = true
    forceImports = true
}
```

However the error persists. Any pointers on what I may be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I haven't had time yet to update the Ceylon Plugin to use Ceylon 1.3.1! Will get this fixed soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because ceylon gradle plugin [does not support yet](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/ceylon-gradle-plugin/issues/16) the new feature --fully-export-maven-dependencies ... I created the issue now ;), so to make your project work you probably need to change **each** subproject/.ceylon/config with these options:

```
[compiler]
source=source
resource=resource

[defaults]
encoding=UTF-8
overrides=build/overrides.xml
flatclasspath=true
fullyexportmavendependencies=false
```

It will disable the new ceylon feature and uses ceylon gradle plugin feature and the generated overrides.xml file

Comment: Agreed. It seems to me like this is a problem with the Gradle plugin in that, by default, it does much too much. And in this case -- for perfectly legitimate historical reasons -- it's trying to do stuff that Ceylon 1.3.1 already does.

Comment: Thanks! The suggested fix makes the build further. Modules `discovery` and `gateway` build without problems, however `foo`, `bar`, and `foobar` fail with duplicate module imports. I think this is caused by the automatic generation of `overrides.xml` instead of using the provided, see

    source/bar/module.ceylon:2: error: source code imports two different versions of module 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons': version '1.12.4.RELEASE' and version '1.12.5.RELEASE'
    module bar "1.0.0" {

Comment: Right, but theres a issue with the [fix in progress](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/ceylon-gradle-plugin/issues/16), probably it will be fixed in next release and everything will be transparent if you choose gradle or ceylon way to deal with dependencies